# Add refinement to search results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, refinement-panel

When I add the taxonomy refinement panel to the search result page I read in the properties that 'This Web Part requires that Managed Navigation is used for either Global or Current navigation.'

Does this mean that if I have a global navigation done classically, without managed metadata, this refinement panel will never work?

Comment: Why are you not using the "Refinement Web Part" that is designed for the search result page?

Comment: because I thought that the taxonomy refiner was more specific. I added TAGS to the existing refiners and it does find tags, but not the ones belonging to the 'countries' term set I have created. It seems to pick up only the keywords inserted in the 'Enterprise metadata and keyword settings'. Is there a reason why it is not picking up other term sets in the enterprise metadata?

Comment: You need to add that field as refiner, see here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/10/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013/